# How to install bgui for use in Blender BGE

Tags: python, game-engine

I am trying to install bgui based on [this](http://bgui.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting_started.html). I couldn't get it running even though I followed what is written in the docs;

> "After you’ve downloaded Bgui copy the “bgui” folder to where you need
>   to for your project to access it (the current working directory of the
>   project works well). "

But when I have the code `import bgui` in blender python script, it shows the error

```
ImportError: No module named bgui
```

in debug console.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 uses relative import. Use `import .bgui` instead of `import bgui`

If that's not the problem, do the example scene run okay? You should see a bunch of widgets on the screen.

Comment: What I understood is, if you want to import bgui, there should be a file with that name; bgui here. But I couldn't find any file by that name in the downloaded source

Comment: Not necessarily a file. In this case, Python is looking for a folder called bgui, and within it, there should be a __init__.py file.